# Typescript conditional types aren't inferred as expected

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to build a simple Select component, that can handle both singular and multiple selections. I want it to be typesafe, so as far as I understood I can set the type of component's value depending on its `isMultiselect` property, so this is how it went:

The value type:

```js
type ISelectItem = {label: string, value: string};

// conditional type - or at least how I thought it should work
type ISelectValue<TIsMultiselect extends boolean> = TIsMultiselect extends true ? Array<ISelectItem> : ISelectItem;
```

The component props type:

```js
type IAutocompleteSelectProps<TIsMultiselect extends boolean> = {
    items: ISelectItem[]; // items to select from
    value?: ISelectValue<TIsMultiple>; // component value
    setValue: (value: ISelectValue<TIsMultiple>) => void; // function to set the value from the outside
    isMultiselect: TIsMultiselect; // flag defining if we have singular or multiple values
}
```

And the component itself (only relevant part):

```js
function AutocompleteSelect<TIsMultiselect extends boolean>({
    items,
    onSearch,
    setValue,
    value,
    isMultiselect,
}: IAutocompleteSelectProps<TIsMultiselect>) {

    const selectValue = (item: ISelectItem) => {
        if (isMultiselect) {
            value
                // TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISelectValue ',
                // and Type 'ISelectValue ' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
                ? setValue([...value, item])
                // TS2345: Argument of type 'ISelectItem []' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISelectValue '.
                : setValue([item]);
        } else {
            // TS2345: Argument of type 'ISelectItem ' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISelectValue '.
            setValue(item);
        }
    }

    // ...rest of the component logic
}
```

I'd expect TS to understand, that if `isMultiselect` is true, so the value should contain an array of items, and only one item otherwise. Instead, it tells me that I misunderstood something here, but after extensive googling I can't figure out what :(

Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgyhANhAxsGwIFsoF4oDeiAhgEZIBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0UAbsYgK4RVajVgF8A3AChQkWAmRoAaj34AeACoxqAWV6JgDaklTAoEAB6YmAE2pRSAe3vJiTAHx4oG7bv2H5J80sbKHp+KAB+KABBOjpiEBV4IzQMbHcqJP9UrEkpcGgYKN5gexR7LDBkTDljAAU6ezBqdU0dPQNkgIsIa1sHJwgXd3wCCShxqAZMLGoMmpTpgG0AXUkJqHsmBGI6FAALKgAKAEd+OhBBemYWAEo8d057Bis1ie4+CHC5zqUPlu92n5jK5XuNDMBfvwju8obIfsoIP82r5Oq47rgHk8XmMJgZkR1-FQvPigWhJCIJBIAGa8JhoBibaLFUrlSoQaqdJE+AnGUzdXp2RzONyHUbrKbYahsHHjTbbXZ7aXrcGQiBKt4I9XjPHc0nAaUiDJFEplCpVCDzYD1RrNYm61F3UYyqBlJi0Gjwj4eQ4SrDfLLTdHuMXrXFUqA+gEo-yO52hjUfOPx0MAehTnjgACYAMwAFgArFQYixeFgeiZ7OHpNAAOQuEArGuTWxMewmYjUagMFhMMjIEL2KBgHbEMuYOgbKv5KA1zLGVUzrXJ+NpqAuKyeaezy0LptYXjuvbETjQYgzxZwEBYByIAB0EriJToy0ONz37L29g3wCPJjo7N4Og3TXJhJnHYgn1vJNl3GSIVQRQ5FlvZCYTVMDsGWG5oJg1c1CzPNC2iOgSzLJgKynGRt06bIoEbZsoFbdtO27XtSH7EohxHMcIAnSsQi3OdFARGcoJg5NBHZVVEN9TDQVDERTEQQxCGw9ZcPwgsi2I0ty0nfjKME9BphnejGLXZiez7aAOOHOJuN4ija0M3dRLEj0IQQ30bjk9YKV8yk1PTZDb3-d0+J-aBTTATZdMQewWAYFAAomf9gEA0Ca2ocpoAAK2oMwQl-dzbAirgERrCQRCAA)

Comment: There is nothing in `IAutocompleteSelectProps` that tells TS that there is a relation between some of the members. Google discriminated unions. That's usually how you handle that sort of thing. Oh, right. That's what the answer is already telling you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using generic, please consider to do the following:

```
type IAutocompleteSelectSingleProps = {
  isMultiselect: false;
  value?: ISelectItem;
  setValue: (value: ISelectItem) => void;
};
type IAutocompleteSelectMultiProps = {
  isMultiselect: true;
  value?: ISelectItem[];
  setValue: (value: ISelectItem[]) => void;
};

type IAutocompleteSelectProps = IAutocompleteSelectBaseProps &
  (IAutocompleteSelectMultiProps | IAutocompleteSelectSingleProps);
```

This way, your props will always have `IAutocompleteSelectBaseProps`, and depending on the value of `isMultiselect`, you will have either `IAutocompleteSelectMultiProps` or `IAutocompleteSelectSingleProps`.

Also, depending on whether you use `strictNullChecks` tsconfig option or not, you will have to add `if(isMultiselect === true)` to make it work as expected. You will have to add `===` in case if you do not use `strictNullChecks`.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoYKlN)